# Is there any way to init BOTH key and value at the same time in javascript objects with ternary operator?

Tags: javascript, syntax, initialization, javascript-objects

for example, I want a javascript object having different key-value according to a==0:

```
var v=a==1?{
  "a":"1",
}:{
  "b":"2",
};
```

I want to simplify to something like:

```
var v={
  a==1?("a":"1"):("b":"2"),
};
```

and hence for more conditions:

```
var v={
  a==1?("a":"1"):("b":"2"),
  c==1?("c":"3"):("d":"4"),
  .
  .
  .
  "commonKey1":"commonValue1",
  "commonKey2":"commonValue2"
};
```

Which init both key and value using ternary operator, but I tried the syntax above and it is not working, is there any correct syntax to do this?

Comment: There are options with ES6 syntax

    `const a = 1;
    const b = 2;
    const c = a==1? {a}: {b}`

But that depends on the full scenario to understand what you want to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

When there are multiple conditions and common values, `Object.assign` is probably the clearest way to do it:

```js
const a = 2;
const c = 1;
const v = Object.assign({ commonKey1: 'commonValue1', commonKey2: 'commonValue2' },
  a==1?{"a":"1"}:{"b":"2"},
  c==1?{"c":"3"}:{"d":"4"}
);
console.log(v);
```

Another possibility (that looks uglier IMO) is to *spread* the object returned by the conditional operator into the parent object:

```js
const a = 1;
const v = {
  foo: 'bar',
  ...(a==1? {"a":"1"}:{"b":"2"})
};
console.log(v);
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm afraid there is not. Because an object can be used as a key, if you write it like this, the computer cannot recognize what you really want. For example:

```
var t = {name:'y'};
var m = {t};
```

Have you missed the value?

```
var m = {t:'expert'}
```

Or you just want `m = t`

```
var m = {name:'y'}
```

It may be confused.